# Condition for multi tone AM for proper envelope detection

Tags: communication, modulation, amplitude-modulation

Given a multi-tone amplitude modulated wave as follows :

s(t) = A<sub>c</sub>[1+2k<sub>a</sub>sin(w<sub>1</sub>) + k<sub>a</sub>sin(w<sub>2</sub>)] cos(w<sub>c</sub>t)

where w<sub>c</sub> is the carrier frequency and w<sub>1</sub> and w<sub>2</sub> are the modulating frequency components. My question is : what is the largest value of amplitude sensitivity k<sub>a</sub> for which **envelope detection** can be performed on s(t) to recover the message signal without distortion ?

**Method 1** (calculate effective modulation index)

Effective modulation index for multi-tone AM signal is given by \$u_{eff}=\sqrt{u_1^2+u_2^2}\$  (u<sub>eff</sub> = sqrt(u<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + u<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>) where u<sub>1</sub> and u<sub>2</sub> represent modulation index for single tone AM signal and *sqrt* stands for square-root. By definition, u = maximum value of message signal after modulation.So u<sub>1</sub> = 2K<sub>a</sub> and u<sub>2</sub> = K<sub>a</sub>. In the case of single tone AM wave, for envelope detector to work without any distortion, the condition is u<=1. Analogously for multi-tone AM wave the same condition becomes u<sub>eff</sub><=1.

4k<sub>a</sub><sup>2</sup> + k<sub>a</sub><sup>2</sup> <= 1

*k<sub>a</sub><=0.2*

**Method 2**

Here again we take analogy from single-tone AM for envelope detection condition. However, instead of u<sub>eff</sub><=1, we do

u<sub>1</sub> + u<sub>2</sub> <=1

2k<sub>a</sub> + k<sub>a</sub> <= 1

*k<sub>a</sub> <= 0.33*

Please tell me which of one of these two methods is correct ?

(Sorry for poor formatting. I am a novice to MathJax )

Comment: Apart from the answer, can someone please tell me how to format my question correctly ? Like I couldn't get square root symbol to come on screen, etc.

Comment: it's probably easier to use mathjax for the more complicated equations, I've done one for you as an example

Comment: Thanks a lot @Neil

Comment: note how the curly brackets are used, to group things for the sub _ operator, or group terms under the sqrt operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not take the modulation index to mess this, because you already have the time domain expression for the modulated output s(t).

I guess you only forgot to insert t. I mean you planned to write this:

s(t) = A<sub>c</sub>[1+2k<sub>a</sub>sin(w<sub>1</sub>t) + k<sub>a</sub>sin(w<sub>2</sub>t)] cos(w<sub>c</sub>t)

Distortion (see NOTE1) occurs if the amplitude term goes momentarily to negative. To prevent it means you keep 1+2k<sub>a</sub>sin(w<sub>1</sub>t) + k<sub>a</sub>sin(w<sub>2</sub>t) non-negative.

The worst case occurs when the sines happen to be at the same time =-1.

You want 1-2k<sub>a</sub>- k<sub>a</sub> >0 i.e. k<sub>a</sub> < 1/3 as you have already written.

NOTE1: The distortion gets its birth in the common envelope detector(= diode detector). Synchronous detector (=mixing the signal back down) doesn't have that problem.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your answer !